# How to bind filtered result to another action with Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to develop action bar with search functionality.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/lWoHw7Aiwacln4GAHfNm?p=preview

The action bar updates when selecting/deselecting files without any search query; however, I now want to bind the action bar to filtered result after entering a search query.

For example:

1. Select **File A** (Notice: *Delete* and *Open* actions are added)
2. Enter **a** in the search input. (Bug: Since there is only ONE item in the filtered result, I want the selectState to change to *all*. This will cause *Select All* to be replaced by *Deselect All*.)
3. Remove **a** form the search input. (Another Bug: Notice at this point selectState changes to *all*. Now *Select All* is replaced by *Deselect All*, but that is wrong because the filtered result now has a lot more elements and we haven't selected everything.)

```
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.compat.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="FilesCtrl">
    <h1>Search + Bar</h1>
    <input ng-change="updateSelectState()" ng-model="search" type="text" placeholder="search" />

    <div class="files_bar">
       <ul>
         <li ng-show="selectState == 'none' || selectState == 'one' || selectState == 'multiple'" ng-click="selectAll()">
           <span>Select All</span>
         </li>
         <li ng-show="selectState == 'all'" ng-click="deselectAll()">
           <span>Deselect All</span>
         </li>
         <li ng-show="selectState == 'one' || selectState == 'multiple' || selectState == 'all'" ng-click="confirmView()">
           <span>Delete</span>
         </li>
         <li ng-show="selectState == 'one'">
           <span>Open</span>
         </li>
       </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="files">
        <div class="file" ng-repeat="file in filteredFiles = ( files | filter:{ name: search })">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="file.checked" ng-click="toggleFileSelect(file)">
          {{file.name}}
        </div>

        <div ng-if="filteredFiles.length == 0">
          <h4>No file found.</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like `filteredFiles` doesn't update until after the digest cycle is complete.

Comment: @AnthonyChu do you have a suggestions on how I can update `filteredFiles` earlier or execute `updateSelectState` later?

Comment: Can think of a few ways, the hackiest is to put the `updateSelectState` code in a `$timeout`. Other ideas would be use a watch or ngChange to update `updateSelectState` with the filtered result.